# Cannot read property 'length' of undefined error when passing collection of models to a CollectionView in Marionette

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I am working in Backbone/Marionette and have a Collection, where I am parsing data, and creating a collection of models, which I then pass to a CollectionView, and a childView is set for that CollectionView.

The collection successfully makes it into the CollectionView, but it seems when my app attempts to display the childView, I get an `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`

The error gets thrown in marionette here:

```
_filteredSortedModels: function(addedAt) {
      var viewComparator = this.getViewComparator();
      var models = this.collection.models;
      addedAt = Math.min(Math.max(addedAt, 0), models.length - 1);
```

it appears as though "models" is undefined here.

My app is set up this way:

DrawerCollection:

```
App.module('Home.Drawer.Collections', function (Collections, App, Backbone, Marionette) {
 model: App.Home.Drawer.Models.DrawerModel,
    ...make a request, parse some data...

 responseData.push( new App.Home.Drawer.Models.DrawerModel({

     ...model properties...
});

 var DrawerLayoutCollection = new App.Home.DrawerCollectionView({collection: responseData});
App.mainContainer.show(shelfLayoutCollection);
```

DrawerView:

```
App.module('Home', function(Home, App, Backbone, Marionette) {
Home.DrawerComponent = Backbone.Marionette.LayoutView.extend({
 ...my template, events, ui, etc....
});

});
```

Collection View (which has the DrawerView set to be its childView):

```
 Home.DrawerCollectionView = Backbone.Marionette.CollectionView.extend({
        childView: Home.DrawerComponent

    });
```

Any input would be much appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0):

Few things seem wrong with this line:

```
var DrawerLayoutCollection = new App.Home.DrawerCollectionView({collection: responseData});
```

First, `DrawerLayoutCollection` is not a constructor, but an instance. 
Second, it's called a *collection* but it's actually a view instance.

You are passing `responseData` as a collection to the collection view instead of an actual backbone collection.

It should be something like

```
var drawerLayoutCollectionView = new App.Home.DrawerCollectionView({collection: new Backbone.Collection(responseData)});
```